# Cakephp 3.x save one to one relation

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0, one-to-one

I'm working on cakephp with mySQL. I defined a One to one relationship:
One Camada has one Grupo.-

I've designed a form where the users inputs information for both entities

I'm trying to save the relationship, but the camada entity never has a reference of GRUPO_id and it's not allow to persist.

Here's the code in my CamadasController:

```
    public function add() {
    $camada = $this->Camadas->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $camada = $this->Camadas->patchEntity($camada, $this->request->data, [
            'associated' => [
                'Grupos'
            ]
        ]);

        $camada->grupos = TableRegistry::get('Grupos')->newEntity();

        $camada->usuario_creacion = 2;
        $camada->fecha_creacion = date("d/m/Y");
        $camada->eliminado = 0;
        $camada->grupos->eliminado = 0;
        $camada->grupos->fecha_creacion = Time::now();
        $camada->usuario_creacion = 2;

        if ($this->Camada->saveAssociated($camada)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('La camada fue guardada'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('La camada no pudo ser guardada. Por favor, intente nuevamente'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('camada'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['camada']);
}
```

The error that I get is the following:
Call to a member function saveAssociated() on boolean

at line: if ($this->Camada->saveAssociated($camada)) {

[UPDATE: AFTER CHANGES]

```
    public function add() {
    $camada = $this->Camadas->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $camada = $this->Camadas->patchEntity($camada, $this->request->data, [
            'associated' => [
                'Grupos'
            ]
        ]);

        $camada->grupos = TableRegistry::get('Grupos')->newEntity();
        $camada->usuario_creacion = 2;
        $camada->fecha_creacion = date("d/m/Y");
        $camada->eliminado = 0;
        $camada->grupos->eliminado = 0;
        $camada->grupos->fecha_creacion = Time::now();
        $camada->grupos->usuario_creacion = 2;

        if ($this->Camadas->save($camada)) {
            echo $camada->grupos_id;
            $this->Flash->success(__('La camada fue guardada'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('La camada no pudo ser guardada. Por favor, intente nuevamente'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('camada'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['camada']);
}
```

ERROR:
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kick`.`camadas`, CONSTRAINT `camadas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`grupos_id`) REFERENCES `GRUPOS` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

> object(App\Model\Entity\Camada) {

```
'grupo' => object(App\Model\Entity\Grupo) {

    'nombre' => 'test',
    'contrato' => 'test',
    'eliminado' => (int) 0,
    'fecha_creacion' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {},
    'usuario_creacion' => (int) 2,
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ],
    '[original]' => [[maximum depth reached]],
    '[virtual]' => [[maximum depth reached]],
    '[errors]' => [[maximum depth reached]],
    '[invalid]' => [[maximum depth reached]],
    '[repository]' => 'Grupos'

},
'descripcion' => 'test',
'año' => (int) 29837,
'contacto1' => 'lkjsdf',
'contacto2' => 'kjfsdf',
'usuario_creacion' => (int) 2,
'fecha_creacion' => '06/02/2017',
'eliminado' => (int) 0,
'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2017-02-06T05:26:21+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

},
```

Comment: You are completely doing wrong..which version of cakephp you are using? You are mixing cakephp 2 and cakephp 3 together..

Comment: Ok.. just checked and it's  3.3.13

Comment: then simply use save instead of saveAssociated..

Comment: I've tried.-

Just changed saveAssociated and used save. Same error:
Call to a member function save() on boolean